# Disable PrimeNg accordion expand behavior without disabling the whole header

Tags: angular, primeng, accordion

I'm using PrimeNg accordion in my app. Besides expand/collapse button I have some other buttons in accordion's header.

I would like to be able to disable accordion's ability to expand but at the same time keep other buttons in accordion's header usable.

Unfortunately when I disable an accordion with *disabled* property, the whole accordion gets disabled and other buttons that are present in my header are not usable too. Is there a way to disable expanding but at the same time keep other stuff I have in my header usable?

Comment: show the failed attempt please.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like event is getting propagated up in the tree. You can stop the propagation using `event.stopPropagation()`.

Like as you mentioned you have some buttons which are also used to trigger some other actions. You can pass the `$event` object from the bound event something like:

In your template:

```
<button (click)="doSomething($event)">Do something</button>
```

In the component class file:

```
doSomething(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // other code execution
}
```

Comment: Wow, After spending 2 days on this issue, got fixed now